# Unix-domain Socket

Tags: postgresql, unix-sockets

I'm trying to set my server up and came across some troubles related to Unix domain sockets. I don't have so much experience with Unix, despite the stack for web development: Apache, PHP and SQL. I installed Apache and PostgreSQL, but trying to access the `psql` shell I came across the following error:

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

My `pg_hbs.conf`has this appearence:

| TYPE | DATABASE | USER | ADDRESS | METHOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| local | all | root/postgres/home (all was tried already) |  |  |
| IPv4 |  |  |  |  |
| host | all | root | 127.0.0.1:5232 | scram-sha-256 |
| IPv6 |  |  |  |  |
| host | all | root | ::1/128 | scram-sha-256 |

The error references the "local" field in the config file. I just opened up some documentation about Unix sockets, it's very interesting, and I will want to know more about but, despite looking like "I'd be to recreating the wheel", I just want to set the environment for development right now.

Any help will be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the command you used to access the psql shell?

Comment: @BrahimGaabab, focus please... psql

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the psql shell as root, you should type this entire command line: (not just `psql`)

`su - postgres`

Comment: It works! Thanks.

Comment: And the reason WHY this works is that postgresql has its own database of user accounts which is **entirely separate** from the unix system accounts. When `psql` is run, it tries to use the current unix username as the postgres username (unless the `-U` option is used). `root` does not have a postgres account. User `postgres` does. There should be an entry in `pg_hba.conf` similar to `local all all peer` (or at least just one for the postgres user: `local all postgres peer`). The `peer` method allows local unix users to login via socket to the same pg username in postgres without a password.

Comment: See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html for info about client authentication, and chapter 22 for info about roles.   The documentation for the postgres [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html) command is worth reading too (BTW, "CREATE USER" is an alias/synonym for CREATE ROLE).